# ¿Como puedo solucionar el cannot Get/ al publicar mi app de Angular?

Tags: angular

Se agregaron nuevas cosas a una aplicación ya existente, al momento de generar la nueva carpeta del dist con el **ng build --prod** y remplazar los archivos nuevos en la carpeta del dist que ya existia, si muestra la pagina principal de la app, pero al querer acceder a otra me aparece el "Cannot GET/", me gustaría saber como solucionarlo.

Comment: Hola. Por favor actualiza tu pregunta con los comandos que utilizaste para generar el build.

Comment: en la consola utilice el comano ng build --prod

Comment: Cuando corres el servidor con `ng server` no te da error? Como estas probando el build? En un servidor apache? Tienes `<base href="/" >` definido?

Comment: Cuando lo prueno en **ng serve** corre correcto, como puedo verificar esto? <base href="/" >

Comment: Debe ir en el index.html,